# Convert a list `[1, 2, 3]` to a string '{1, 2, 3}' in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to convert lists like `[1, 3, 2]` or `[1,3]` or `[1,4,5]` to strings of the form `'{1, 3, 2}'`, `'{1, 3}'` `'{1, 4, 5}'`.

I can think of a couple of ways to do this, but not an elegant one. I was wondering how you would solve this. Is there elegant solution possible?

Comment: '{' + array.join(', ') + '}'

Comment: @RainingChain thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

```
var result = '{'+ input[0];

for(var index = 1; index < input.length; index++) {
   result = result + ' '+ input[index];
}
result = result + '}';
```

or

```
var result = '{' + input.join(', ')+ '}';
```

remember to give an space after ','.

Comment: my mistake. it would be join

Answer (score 1):

Use `.join()` method

ex:

```
var arr = [1,3,2];

var str = arr.join();
```

hope this helps

Comment: The `.join()` method is definitely the way to go, but the code shown here doesn't produce the desired output format.

Comment: try this to get the desired format : '{' + arr.join() + '}'

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [1,3,2];
var str ="{" + arr + "}"; // let the cast to string do your work {1,3,2}

// and if you really want spaces after your commas, add the below
str = str.replace(/,/g, ", "); // {1, 3, 2}
```